# How I can split file in Android Case The File Is Large To Upload It(Sound File)

Tags: java, android

How I can split file in Android Case The File Is Large To Upload It(Sound File)
I use zip4j but how i can split it when Mack it zip or any way to split To upload It this my code when zip

```
private static void compress(String inputFile, String compressedFile) {
    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(compressedFile);
        File inputFileH = new File(inputFile);


        //Initiate Zip Parameters which define various properties
        ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();

        // set compression method to deflate compression
        parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);


        //DEFLATE_LEVEL_FASTEST     - Lowest compression level but higher speed of compression
        //DEFLATE_LEVEL_FAST        - Low compression level but higher speed of compression
        //DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL  - Optimal balance between compression level/speed
        //DEFLATE_LEVEL_MAXIMUM     - High compression level with a compromise of speed
        //DEFLATE_LEVEL_ULTRA       - Highest compression level but low speed
        parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);

        //Set the encryption flag to true
        parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);

        //Set the encryption method to AES Zip Encryption
        parameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);

        //AES_STRENGTH_128 - For both encryption and decryption
        //AES_STRENGTH_192 - For decryption only
        //AES_STRENGTH_256 - For both encryption and decryption
        //Key strength 192 cannot be used for encryption. But if a zip file already has a
        //file encrypted with key strength of 192, then Zip4j can decrypt this file
        parameters.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);

        // file compressed
        zipFile.addFile(inputFileH, parameters);
        long uncompressedSize = inputFileH.length();
        File outputFileH = new File(compressedFile);
        long comrpessedSize = outputFileH.length();

        //System.out.println("Size "+uncompressedSize+" vs "+comrpessedSize);
        double ratio = (double) comrpessedSize / (double) uncompressedSize;
        System.out.println("File compressed with compression ratio : " + ratio);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void decompress(String compressedFile, String destination) {
    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(compressedFile);
        if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
            zipFile.setPassword("123");
        }
        zipFile.extractAll(destination);
    } catch (ZipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("File 

Decompressed");
    }
}
```

can any one help me.....??

Comment: Please show an example code

Answer (score 9):

The Permission You Need to Run The Process

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Defined This Variable To Locate Size Of Parts....

```
 public static final long floppySize = (long)(1.4 * 1024 * 1024);
/** the maximum size of each file "chunk" generated, in bytes */
public static long chunkSize = (long)(1.4 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Type The Path Of Your File

```
String ss = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/1.amr";

    try {
        //split(ss);
        //join(ss);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Method To Split.....

```
 public static void split(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    // open the file
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));

    // get the file length
    File f = new File(filename);
    long fileSize = f.length();

    // loop for each full chunk
    int subfile;
    for (subfile = 0; subfile < fileSize / chunkSize; subfile++)
    {
        // open the output file
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename + "." + subfile));

        // write the right amount of bytes
        for (int currentByte = 0; currentByte < chunkSize; currentByte++)
        {
            // load one byte from the input file and write it to the output file
            out.write(in.read());
        }

        // close the file
        out.close();
    }

    // loop for the last chunk (which may be smaller than the chunk size)
    if (fileSize != chunkSize * (subfile - 1))
    {
        // open the output file
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename + "." + subfile));

        // write the rest of the file
        int b;
        while ((b = in.read()) != -1)
            out.write(b);

        // close the file
        out.close();
    }

    // close the file
    in.close();
}
```

The Method To Join By File Name Only.....

```
 public static void join(String baseFilename) throws IOException
{
    int numberParts = getNumberParts(baseFilename);

    // now, assume that the files are correctly numbered in order (that some joker didn't delete any part)
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(baseFilename));
    for (int part = 0; part < numberParts; part++)
    {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(baseFilename + "." + part));

        int b;
        while ( (b = in.read()) != -1 )
            out.write(b);

        in.close();
    }
    out.close();
}
```

The Method To Get Number Of Part.....

```
private static int getNumberParts(String baseFilename) throws IOException
{
    // list all files in the same directory
    File directory = new File(baseFilename).getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();
    final String justFilename = new File(baseFilename).getName();
    String[] matchingFiles = directory.list(new FilenameFilter()
    {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {
            return name.startsWith(justFilename) && name.substring(justFilename.length()).matches("^\\.\\d+$");
        }
    });
    return matchingFiles.length;
}
```